# Is there a way to get index of one item in sorted results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create html link to specific item in sorted results with pagination.

Real world example would be a forum thread with many replies - to show right page of the paginated results i need to know how many replies ware made before the item.
(To divide by number of post per page ).

What query would give such number (index of one item in results set)?

**EDIT**
One might add such index to each post (increment secondary id field) assuming that each post would have only one parent.

But i'd like to know if there is better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to elasticsearch forum and it seems that there is no such function.